# Jenkins-JIRA-Issue updater

Tags: web-services, soap, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jira-plugin

I am using Jenkins-JIRA issue updater plug in to update JIARs after build is complete. and getting below error message in Jenkins log for it. Don't understand what is wrong. Any suggestions please !!

Tried to access JIRA url with same credentials outside Jenkins and it worked fine. So seems like issue is on Jenkins side.

```
org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair convertJSON
WARNING: 'stapler-class' is deprecated: info.bluefloyd.jenkins.IssueUpdatesBuilder
info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPSession <init>
INFO: SOAP Session service endpoint at http://JIRA_SOAP_URL/
info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPSession connect
INFO: Connnecting via SOAP as : $USER_NAME
info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPClient authenticateSoapSession
SEVERE: Could not connect to Jira via SOAP.
AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail: 
    {http://xml.apache.org/axis/}stackTrace:org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startDTD(DeserializationContext.java:1161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.doctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.doctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.client.JirasoapserviceV2SoapBindingStub.login(JirasoapserviceV2SoapBindingStub.java:3790)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPSession.connect(SOAPSession.java:47)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPClient.authenticateSoapSession(SOAPClient.java:46)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPClient.connect(SOAPClient.java:40)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.IssueUpdatesBuilder.perform(IssueUpdatesBuilder.java:168)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
```

{http://xml.apache.org/axis/}hostname:My_Computer_name

```
org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
    at org.apache.axis.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:701)
    at org.apache.axis.Message.getSOAPEnvelope(Message.java:435)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.MustUnderstandChecker.invoke(MustUnderstandChecker.java:62)
    at org.apache.axis.client.AxisClient.invoke(AxisClient.java:206)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invokeEngine(Call.java:2784)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2767)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2443)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:2366)
    at org.apache.axis.client.Call.invoke(Call.java:1812)
    at com.atlassian.jira.rpc.soap.client.JirasoapserviceV2SoapBindingStub.login(JirasoapserviceV2SoapBindingStub.java:3790)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPSession.connect(SOAPSession.java:47)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPClient.authenticateSoapSession(SOAPClient.java:46)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.SOAPClient.connect(SOAPClient.java:40)
    at info.bluefloyd.jenkins.IssueUpdatesBuilder.perform(IssueUpdatesBuilder.java:168)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:199)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:533)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1759)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Processing instructions are not allowed within SOAP messages
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startDTD(DeserializationContext.java:1161)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.doctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.doctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.parse(DeserializationContext.java:227)
    at org.apache.axis.SOAPPart.getAsSOAPEnvelope(SOAPPart.java:696)
    ... 22 more
```

[image]

Comment: give a screenshot of the settings (you can delete credentials on it)

Comment: Updated screen shot of configs in original question!!

Comment: Also i tried to pass URL, JQL, COMMENT and custoimfield as variable. $URL and ${URL} etc. but still issue exist.

Comment: Are you sure SOAP is turned on in your jira settings? try to go https://JIRA_HOST/rest/api/2/issue/ISSUE-1 (input any of the existing issues). Is it working and outputting json?

Comment: tried it this URL,  Got "issue doesn't exit". I picked a random JIRA number may be this is why. But this is using "rest" right? Plug-in use "SOAP".

Comment: Which version are you using? Jira SOAP is deprecated since 6.0 and will be totally removed in 7.0 (https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/creating-a-jira-soap-client)

Comment: We are at JIRA 6.3.9

Comment: but is it enabled? https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-api-status/jira-rpc-services/enabling-the-rpc-plugin

Comment: Nowadays, the REST API is the way to go (https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis), and the Jenkins Jira Issue Updater Plugin has been updated to use that: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira+Issue+Updater+Plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks to all those who tried to help !!

This Jenkins JIRA issue updater plug-in is very sensitive about JIRA SOAP URL.
Earlier other plug-in was accepting URL as http://JIRA_HOST_NAME:PORT_NUMBER. But this plug-in expect more then this. I tried http://JIRA_HOST_NAME:PORT_NUMBER/rpc/soap/jirasoapservice-v2 and it worked.